# Iterations of Sum of Digits

Tags: combinatorics

Define $f(n)$ to be the number of iterations of the sum of the digits of a number that must be performed to reduce the number to a single digit. For example, $f(9) = 0$, and $f(92) = 2$ ($92 \implies 9 + 2 = 11 \implies 1 + 1 = 2$). Compute the following sum:

$\sum_{k=1}^{2023}(-1)^{k+1} f(k)$

I see that grouping every two consecutive terms may help, but I can't see a pattern beyond there. Every ten digits, there will be two consecutive ones that have different values for this function. f(19) = 2, but f(20) = 1 -- though I don't know how to generalize this.

Comment: I suggest computing this for numbers smaller than $2023$.   But please edit your post to describe the source of this problem.  Questions involving the current year frequently feature in competitions and such.

Comment: I came up with this problem randomly myself.

Comment: In that case, there is no particular reason to expect any solution significantly better than brute force (which isn't terribly hard, at least with a machine).  But you could at least try smaller numbers to see if there is some sensible way to organize the values.

Comment: Answer looks to be 67 with some code.

Comment: Yes, that's what I got (though I didn't take care to debug the code carefully).

Answer (score 2):

I got the value of $67$ from this very simples python code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

f = []
for n in range(10000):
    ans = 0 # f(n)
    while n>=10:
        aux = n
        sum = 0 # sum of the digits
        while aux>0:
            sum+=(aux%10) # add last digit
            aux//=10      # remove last digit
        n = sum
        ans+=1
    f.append(ans)

w = 0  # Wenger's summation
a = []
for k in range(10000):
    w+=f[k]*(-1)**(k+1)
    a.append(w)

print(a[2023])
```

Its graph looks very poorly behaved. I doubt there is a good looking closed formula.

[image]

Comment: Did you compute the sum to $2023$ or to $2024$?

Comment: @lulu my mistake. I corrected it already.

Comment: No worries, I was fairly sure of the $67$ and was just checking.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it by hand, note that the first iteration of the sum of digits function $s(n)$  is no greater than $s(1999)=28$ in the region of interest.  We can compute $f(n)$ for $n=1$ to $28$ easily to find
$$f(n)=\begin {cases} 0&1 \le n \le 9\\
1&10\le n \le 18\\
2&n=19\\
1&20 \le n \le 27\\
2&n=28 \end {cases}$$
For $n \gt 28, f(n)=1+f(s(n))$ so we should study where $s(n)$ makes transitions between the categories shown for $f(n)$.  I think you will have to treat each decade of $n$ separately and often they will be split, which leaves a few hundred cases but they will be quick when you get some practice.
$$\begin {array}{r | r} \text{range}&\text {contribution}\\
\hline 1-9&0\\
10-18&-1\\
19&2\\
20-27&0\\
28-29&0\\
30-36&-1\\
37-39&2
\end {array}$$